# Trying to come up with matrix inverses algebraically — how does one do this?

Tags: matrices, inverse, derivations

I've been trying to find the inverse of a matrix through this sort of roundabout manner but to no avail. Sure, I could just use the standard way, but I figured working through this particular process would be more intuitive. Anyway, my work goes as follows:

$$AA^{-1} = A^{-1}A=I $$

$$ \text{Let A be} = \pmatrix{2&3\\1&2}$$

---

$$\pmatrix{2&3\\1&2}\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d} = \pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}\pmatrix{2&3\\1&2}=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}$$

Expanding gives:

$$\pmatrix{2a+3c&2b+3d\\a+2c&b+2d} = \pmatrix{2a+b&3a+2b\\2c+d&3c+2d}=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}$$

$$\therefore 2a+3c=2a+b=0$$
$$\therefore 2b+3d=3a+2b=0$$

Solving gives:

$$a = 0, b=1, c=\frac{1}{3}, d=0$$

Hence the derived inverse is:

$$\pmatrix{0&1\\\frac{1}{3}&0}$$

**However, this is not the inverse of the A matrix above. Where is the flaw in this method?**

Comment: I've flagged my own question for deletion/clousre.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it seems there's a typo in your system, as :
$$2a+3c=2a+b=1$$
and not $0$.

Solving this (and checked it with WolframAlpha) gave me $a=2, b=-3, c=-1, d=2$, which seems to be correct.

The system works fine, so good job on the method!

Comment: Oh lord, this is an embarrassing mistake. Thanks a ton.